# upload files to storage account without SAS

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage-account

I need to upload files to an storage account without using SAS.

I create an "app registration" and give contributor access to the storage account.

If I want to upload files from powershell? How can I do it?

First az login? and then azcopy? Because I tried this way but ask me for a token

Comment: tou need to grant different kind of roles like `Storage Blob Data Owner` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal#rbac-roles-for-blobs-and-queues) then i'm usre you can find some code samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Azure Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/?view=azps-2.8.0), [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest) and [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10) are three different things, you should not mix them together.

If you want to use powershell to upload file with the service principal, after you create the App Registration, please [get values for signing in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-values-for-signing-in), then [create a new application secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-a-new-application-secret).

In your storage account, the `Contributor` role is enough, but you should note, actually the `Contributor` does not have the permission to access the blob directly, it just let you get the context of the storage account, then use the context to access the blob, to access the blob directly, we need the [`Storage Blob Data Owner/Contributor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal#rbac-roles-for-blobs-and-queues) as mentioned in the comment.

Then use the script below(the `Get-Credential` in another reply is an interactive way, here is a non-interactive way, usually, we use the service principal in a non-interactive way for the automation)

```
$azureAplicationId ="<Application-ID>"
$azureTenantId= "<Tenant-ID>"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "<Application-secret>" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId -ServicePrincipal

$context = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -Name <storageaccount-name>).Context
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container <container-name> -File <localfile-path> -Blob <blob-name> -Context $context
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Service Principal or a certificate to login using azcopy, and then copy your files to the storage account. Please reference [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this.  Since you mentioned PowerShell, I'll use it in this example.

```
# The following assumes you have already created the App registration.
# Either through the portal, PS, whatever.

$creds = Get-Credential

# Uername = Application ID
# password = The service principle secret. You need to create this.

Connect-AzAccount `
    -Credential $creds `
    -Tenant  $tenantId `
    -ServicePrincipal

# you will need to get the storage accounts context.
# There are a few ways to do this I usually just get the storage account

$context = (Get-AzStorageAccount -Name $saName -ResourceGroupName $rgName).Context

# You will need to give the App Registration permissions to upload the blob.
# If you don't assign permissions this cmdlet will fail.

Set-AzStorageBlobContent `
    -Container $containerName `
    -File $filePath `
    -Blob $blobName `
    -Context $context
```